# Substitute variables with random numbers

Tags: matlab, random, substitution

From a computation in Mathematica I got a huge matrix with numbered variables of the form `a[1],...,a[100]` in some of the entries. I would like to import this matrix as a *template* to matlab and then substitute random numbers (normally distributed) in place of the variables.  I am completely unfamiliar with the support of symbolic variables in Matlab and am not sure whether it supports indexed symbolic variables. I would need some function that searches for the `a[k]` and replaces them with a random number.

In Mathematica I have matrices square matrices of length 2^n where which get more and more sparse as n grows and depend on 5*n (yet symbolic) variables a[k]. For n=2 the matrix is not yet sparse at all and looks like (in Mathematica-Code):

> {{a[3] + a[3], a[7] - I a[8], a[10], I a[8]},
>
> {I a[8], +a[6], I a[5], -I a[9] - a[8]},
>
> {a[7] + I a[8], +a[2], I a[5], -a[7]},
>
> {I a[8], a[2], a[2] + I a[15], -a[8]}}

There exists a script `ToMatlab`which converts the Mathematica notation for matrices to the Matlab notation. I have basically all freedom in renaming the variables as it is most suitable for use in Matlab. Now I would like to create a function in Matlab which returns this exact matrix (for fixed n would be sufficient for now, so the matrix is really fixed) and replaces the a[k] with a normally distributed random number.

Comment: Could you give a little more information - make a "toy" example of the data that you have? It sounds like you have a very large (N>>100) matrix with just 100 different symbols in it. Did you store it as a cell array of strings, perhaps?

Comment: Just to clarify - I think you have several steps. 1) Mathematica generates a "huge matrix". 2) you import this matrix into Matlab (how?) 3) you substitute symbols with values. You clearly know how to do (1). Is it both (2) and (3) that you have a problem with?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know perfectly well how to import matrices with numbers in them into Matlab, but I don't know what to do about symbolic matrices. The import is not my main concern however, since I will find some way to automate it, if necessary with some external script. I don't have any idea how to do (3) in Matlab, up to know I only know how to generate vectors of random numbers but I don't see how to substitute such a vector into my symbolic variables.

Comment: You need to clarify how you store the "symbolic variables". Are they a cell array of strings?

Comment: Technically they `a[k]` is the (yet) undefined function a evaluated in k. But they can just be used as indexed variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a cell array of strings (much bigger than this simple example):

```
import = {'a1','a2';'a2','a4'};
```

Then you can replace 100 values with normally distributed random numbers as follows (obviously you will want to replace constants etc with the values you need):

```
newMatrix = zeros(size(import));

% generate 100 random numbers:
mean = 123.45;
stdDev = 21.0;
N = 100;
randVals = randn(1,N) * stdDev + mean;

for ii=1:N
  indx = find(ismember(import, sprintf('a%d',ii)));
  newMatrix(indx) = randVals(ii);
end
```

The new values will be in the matrix `newMatrix`

This is not super efficient; but it may be a start, and it may get other answers flowing (if you can confirm that this does indeed do what you intend - still not 100% sure I understand your question).

Comment: This does not need to be done often, so I guess it is sufficient enough. Thank you!